# Jerky / flickering when loading the animation for RecyclerView in Fragment (using AnimationAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, gridview, android-animation

Jerky when loading the adapter in a Fragment. Im trying to load the RecyclerView with some animation when showing.

This is my Animation class:

```
public class ScaleInAnimationAdapter extends AnimationAdapter {

  private static final float DEFAULT_SCALE_FROM = .9f;
  private final float mFrom;

  public ScaleInAnimationAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
    this(adapter, DEFAULT_SCALE_FROM);
  }

  public ScaleInAnimationAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, float from) {
    super(adapter);
    mFrom = from;
  }

  @Override protected Animator[] getAnimators(View view) {
//    ObjectAnimator.se
    ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", mFrom, 1f);
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", mFrom, 1f);
    return new ObjectAnimator[] { scaleX, scaleY };
  }
}
```

Loading the RecyclerView with animation:

```
adapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(mCardAdapter);
    adapter.setFirstOnly(true);
    adapter.setDuration(900);
    adapter.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(.9f));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

adapter here is nothing but the object of the Animation class above!

The flickering comes only for the 1st time.. If i go to other Fragment and come back the animation works fine but when loading or coming back from an Activity there is Animation problem!

Source from https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators